# Why does Sikulix code not working in JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter, sikuli-x

I have below Sikuli code in the JMeter which is not working.

```
import org.sikuli.script.Pattern;
import org.sikuli.script.Screen;
import org.sikuli.script.FindFailed;
import org.sikuli.script.KeyModifier;
import org.sikuli.script.Match;


Screen screen = new Screen();
Pattern VNCviewer = new Pattern ("C:\\scripts\\patterns\\vnc\\vncviewer.png");
screen.wait(VNCviewer,3);
```

I tried in both Beanshell sampler and JSR223 sampler and in both cases not working. Here is the error Im getting.

JSR223 sampler

```
Response code: 500
```

Response message: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: FindFailed: C:\scripts\patterns\vnc\vncviewer.png: (32x31) in R[0,0 1920x1080]@S(0)
Line 2226, in file Region.java

Beanshell sampler

```
Response code: 500
```

Response message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.sikuli.script.Pattern; import org.sikuli.script.Screen; import org.si . . . '' : Method Invocation screen.wait

This code is working fine in another laptop and JMeter version same (5.0). I tried with different java version also. The file path is correct only and the png file exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that the Sikuli isn't able to find the element matching your `vncviewer.png` image on the screen.

Double check that the content of the `vncviewer.png` is present on the screen. It might also be the case you took the screenshot on a different machine having different screen resolution hence finding fails.

You can try the following:

1. Re-capturing the screenshot on the machine you're running JMeter and replacing the `vncviewer.png` with the "fresh" image from particular that machine
2. Call [Pattern.similar()](http://doc.sikuli.org/javadoc/org/sikuli/script/Pattern.html#similar(float)) function to allow more flexibility so Sikuli would look for "similar" image, not for "exact" image
3. [Enable debug logging for Sikuli](http://doc.sikuli.org/javadoc/org/sikuli/script/Debug.html) by [adding the following system property to JMeter command line:](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)

   ```
   jmeter -Dsikuli.Debug=0 -t /path/to/your/testplan.jmx
   ```